# Is it possible to buy new SSL certificate and not renew the old one?

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate, renewal

Is there a way how to buy a new certificate completely for the same domain from the same registrator (and third party company) even though they offering me renewal?

The reason I want to create a new certificate is that new certificate is much cheaper then renewal. Like -32% or more than renewal.

So is that possible?

Comment: Thats up to the registrator, if you specify where you want to buy it, maybe someone already was in zour situation. Generally, they are capable of detecting that you already have certificate from them, so they are capable of not selling for better price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory this is possible, although

- Terms of service of this CA might forbid it or they might just declare a new certificate with the same credentials as renewing.
- It says a lot how "valuable" the certificates are. In theory renewing should be cheaper because they don't need to verify the certificate owner as much as they did the first time. So this means probably that there "verification" of the owner isn't much worth.
- If you use a different public key in the certificate (which they might require or would otherwise consider it renewing) there might be problems with certificate pinning or external certificate checks.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's possible.You will need a new CSR for the domain and buy a new certificate.I didn't tried this, but in my knowledge it's possible.